# Subscribe Google Pub/sub topic to Cloud Storage Avro file gives me "quota exceeded" error - in a beginners tutorial?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm going through Google's [Firestore to BigQuery pipeline tutorual](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/modern-data-pipeline-firestore-bigquery-dataflow-templates/index.html?index=..%2F..next17#9) and I've come to step 10 where I should set up an export from my topic to an avro file saved on cloud storage.

However, when I try running the job, after doing exactly what's mentioned in the tutorial, I get an error telling me that my project has insufficient quotas to execute the workflow. In the quota summary of the message, I notice that it says `1230/818 disk GB`. Does that mean that the job requires 1230 GB disk space? Currently, there are only 100 documents in the Firestore?. This seems wrong to me?

[image: Error message about quota]
All my Cloud storage buckets are empty:
[image: My cloud storage buckets (all empty)]

But when I look at the resources used in the first export job I set up (Pubsub Topic to BigQuery) on [page 9](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/modern-data-pipeline-firestore-bigquery-dataflow-templates/index.html?index=..%2F..next17#8), I'm even more confused.

It seems like it's using CRAZY amounts of resources

```
Current vCPUs   
4
Total vCPU time     
2.511 vCPU hr
Current memory  
15 GB
Total memory time   
9.417 GB hr
Current PD  
1.2 TB
Total PD time   
772.181 GB hr
Current SSD PD  
0 B
Total SSD PD time   
0 GB hr
```

Can this be real, or have I done something completely wrong, since all these resources are used? I mean, there's no activity at all, It's just a subscription, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, that step is calling a Cloud Dataflow template ([this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubsubToAvro.java) one to be exact) to read from Pub/Sub and write to GCS. In turn, Cloud Dataflow is using GCE instances (VMs) for its worker pool. Cloud Dataflow is requesting too many resources (GCE instances which need disk, ram, vCPUs etc) and is hitting your project's limit/quota.

You can override the default number of workers (try 1 to start with) and also also set the smallest VM type (n1-standard-1) when configuring the job under `optional parameters`. This should also save you some money too. Bonus!

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It now works :) 

But one more question. It seems to me that for every active subscription for a topic that sends data to BigQuery, a virtual server is constantly running? So no matter how little data we need to send, we are paying around 60$/month for an entire compute engine?

I thought the GCP pub-sub model was similar to something like Lambda -> SNS -> DynamoDB (in AWS terms).

Is there a way to feed data from a Firebase cloud function, into BigQuery without having a server running?

Comment: To be more accurate: What will I lose by just inserting rows into BigQuery by calling the BigQuery API directly from my firebase cloud function, instead of publishing from the function to a topic first? (Given that nobody else is subscribed to the topic)